# How to get Databricks Instance ID programatically?

Tags: databricks, dbutils

Is there any possibility to retrieve Databricks Instance Id (the blurred piece of URL) by executing some code in the notebook cell?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for notebooks, you can get context of the notebooks via dbutils with code like this (in Python, for example):

```py
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook() \
  .getContext().tags().get("browserHostName").get()
```

Then you can parse URL to using regex